# Traceback with bad filename using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, file, file-handling, xlrd

I'm using xlrd to open a ".xlsx" file and read the data from it to modify it. If the filename exists everything is ok. but if the file doesn't exists I get a traceback.

The code that I'm using is (just relevant parts):

```
from xlrd import open_workbook, XLRDError
from xlwt import *
filename = "./resources/tags_meters.xlsx"
bad_filename = "./resources/meters.txt"

# Use this to test bad filenames
filename = bad_filename
```

and afther that I use a function to read check if the file can be opened:

```
def test_book(filename):
    try:
        open_workbook(filename)
    except XLRDError as e:
        print "error is" + e.message
        return False
    else:
        return True

if test_book(filename):
    print "Book Ok ... Opening file"
    wb = open_workbook(filename)
else:
    print "Book not opened"
```

The traceback that I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\excelread.py", line 38, in <module>
    if test_book(filename):
  File ".\excelread.py", line 31, in test_book
    open_workbook(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 395, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './resources/meters.txt'
```

Why the exception is not working? I'm testing this because I need to know if a file exists or not, in case not, I need to create it.

Comment: You're getting an `IOError` not an `XLRDError` - your handler doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only catch the `XLRDError` in your except clause, and an `IOError` occurs when the file doesn't exist.

You can either use the same except clause for both:

```
except(XLRDError, IOError):
    #....
```

Or, maybe better, if you want to treat them differently:

```
except XLRDError:
    # treat this error
    # ...

except IOError:
    # treat the case where file doesn't exist
```

Comment: Thanks! Feeling pretty dumb now for not seeing it.